# Windows Authentication and Custom SQL Profile/Role membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

How would it be best to use windows authentication with custom sql profile and role membership?  We currently grab windows.identity.name (domain/username) and look up information i sql server to retrieve profile and role information.  I would like to make things more efficient by utilizing membership providers.

How would I go about doing this?  We currently develop within corporate environment using mvc and webforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use SqlRoleProvider with Windows authentication. Just configure and enable RoleManager in your Web.config.

Unfortunately, you'll need to manually call the aspnet_Users_CreateUser stored procedure to populate the aspnet_Users table with your users. (The username will be your domain name, e.g., MYDOMAIN\myusername).

With that in place, you can then use the RoleManager API to create roles and associate users to roles, then use `User.IsInRole` to test for role membership.